# I have no way to force Excel to display certain values in text format

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a very simple CSV file

```
ID,STATUS
G185,A
1,A
1-5,A
1-6,A
1-4,A
1-3,A
1-2,A
1-1,A
```

The first column should be a text value. When I open it initially in Excel 2013 I see

[image]

If I force the first column to be "text" format in `Format Cells`, it turns to be

[image]

It really drives me mad.

Any solutions to display it as is?

Comment: You could put the text fields in quotes.

Comment: @AxelKemper I have also tried what you suggested, no impact at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Import Text Wizard in the *Data Tab* and in Step 3 tell the Wizard that the field is *Text*:

[image]

This will get you:

[image]

Comment: That works! But why only this method works fine, but I cannot open CSV directly?

Comment: If you open the file directly *(say by double-clicking)*, Excel will try to "help" you by performing the date conversion.  **You do not want this help.**

Comment: You can also rename the file .txt which will cause the import wizard shown here to open when the file is opened by excel